# Which myths do these wooden carvings depict?

Tags: identification, art, asia, hinduism

I found these wooden tableaux in my grandfather's storage basement after he died. He was an interior decorator in Los Angeles who bought and sold a lot of Asian art pieces, principally Chinese and Japanese ones. These by contrast seem to me to be Indian or Southeast Asian, but I can't perceive the cultural references that would explain them, nor do they have any inscriptions. Some of the characters are in formal poses, some are partying, and some are monkeys, whose presence makes me think there may be Hindu significance. The seven heads at top are reminiscent of the demon Ravana, but he seems to always have ten. For scale, the carvings are each about a meter long. Unfortunately I have no information at all on their age or origins.

**What characters, stories, or events are depicted here?**

[image: Wooden tableaux]

Comment: This might be a better fit to the Mythology & Folklore: https://mythology.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The figure to the left of the multiheaded one in the middle of your top image looks to me to be Hanuman.

Comment: I'd consider this as art, even if religiously themed, and thereby on topic as you want to figure out who/where would have created this.